# How to get the file name from the directory using InputStream in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

I need to get only the file name from the directory using `InputStream`.
I am getting the file name as `abc.tx`t by using `File` as follows,

```
File file = new File("F:\\source\\abc.txt");
file.getAbsoluteFile().getName()  // getting - abc.txt
```

In the same way, I want to get the file name as `abc.txt` exactly as above using `InputStream`.

```
InputStream inputfile= new FileInputStream("F:\\source\\abc.txt");

Field field = inputfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("path");
field.setAccessible(true);
String filePath  = (String)field.get(inputfile);
File fileName = new File(filePath);
```

Could you please help me, how to get only the file name?

Comment: very confusing question. what is `inputfile` ? is it an `InputStream`?

Comment: yes its an InputStream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what you are doing is fragile:

- If the `InputStream` was not a `FileInputStream` it would fail.
- If a future Java releases changes the internals of `FileInputStream`, it may fail.
- It is likely to fail if your code is sandboxed.

It would be much better to keep / pass the value of the parameter you used when instantiating the `FileInputStream`.

Having said that, to get just the filename, you need to use a `File` or `Path` to extract it; e.g.

```
  String justTheFileName = new File(fileName).getName();
```

or

```
  String justTheFileName = Paths.get(fileName).getFileName();
```